# How to access resources when running app in Visual Studio?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, resources, pre-build-event

in my application, I use various resources. I specified pre-build events to copy my resources to output directory. My directory structure looks like this:

```
/Debug/Models/
/Debug/Shaders/
/Debug/Textures/
/Debug/sfero.exe
/Debug/...
```

I want to access these resources relative to the .exe file and that works fine when I run the executable directly from Debug folder, but when I run it in Visual Studio, it is being launched in different directory, thus I cannot access my resources. Obviously, I don't want to copy my resources to location from where Visual Studio runs my application.

Any suggestions?
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can either make your application logic smarter about searching for resources, or you can pass command-line parameters (see the Debugging area of Project Properties) when launching from Visual Studio, passing the path where to look.

Answer (score 2):

The default current directory in Visual Studio is defined as `$(ProjectDir)` - which is by default the location of your vcproj file.

Go to your project's `Properties` -> `Configuration Properties` -> `Debugging` -> `Working Directory` and change it to `$(SolutionDir)$(Configuration)\` or whatever your `Output Directory` points to.